# Placing an object at a specific percentage along an svg path?

Tags: svg, batik

Currently I'm using the `<animateMotion>` element to very quickly animate an object (defined by a path) to the correct end location. 
This is displaying ok in Chrome and I'm not working on getting it working with Batik.

But I'm curious: is there a better way to do this without the animating? To just draw it (at say 80%) along the length of a `<path>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're creating a static svg image then you should know in advance exactly where to place the object. You can e.g use a [`transform`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#TransformAttribute) attribute to place the object where you want it.

If you're doing it without prior knowledge of where you want to place the object, then you can use javascript, the [getPointAtLength](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#__svg__SVGPathElement__getPointAtLength) method will give you a point on the path at a given length offset. You can query the computed total length of the path by calling [getTotalLength](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#__svg__SVGPathElement__getTotalLength).